# Just loop the script

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have this script that I made.

```
#!/bin/bash

R=$[ (RANDOM % 25 ) + 1 ]
c=$[ (RANDOM % 80 ) + 1 ]
CO=$[ (RANDOM % 7 ) + 1 ]

tput setf $CO
tput cup $R $C
echo "New Position"
```

The script is written to jump around the screen echoing "New position" and changing color. My problem is, is that I need it to loop it "10" times and all the examples that I have found on the internet use some sort of positional parameter input. Or some type of input variable. I have tried using

```
for now in {1..10}
do
my script starting at tput
sleep 1 
done
```

but it does not work or throws an error code and acts as if the extra parts of the added script were not there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to retrofit my script with a for loop that works that does not need a positional parameter.

Comment: If you loop over the `tput` part only, the random numbers are set only once; you have to loop over your whole script.

Comment: Also, `$[ ]` is ancient and not even documented for Bash any longer, you should use `$(( ))` instead.

Comment: So I need to loop over the deceleration as well?

Comment: Yes, or the values for `R`, `c` and `CO` won't change.

Comment: sweet thank you soo much!! I am learning from the old BASH book so that is why I have [ instead of (( but I will take note. Thanks again.

Comment: I made the change and now its throwing an unexpected token error for my declaration lines that worked prior to moving the. for now line above it. It worked fine prior, any guess?

Comment: I forgot to move the "do"..opps

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the whole script in your for loop; the variables are set only once otherwise, and looking at their values doesn't repeat what happened when they were first defined:

```
#!/bin/bash

for now in {1..10}; do
    r=$(( (RANDOM % 25 ) + 1 ))
    c=$(( (RANDOM % 80 ) + 1 ))
    co=$(( (RANDOM % 7 ) + 1 ))

    tput setf $co
    tput cup $r $c
    echo "New Position"
done

tput sgr0
```

I've also replaced `$[ ]` by `$(( ))` as the former is deprecated (and not even documented for Bash any longer), replaced your uppercase variable names by lower case ones (uppercase is [reserved for environment variables used by the shell and utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)) and reset the colour after the loop.

Finally, while it's almost always good practice to quote your variables as in `tput cup "$r" "$c"`, it's not required here as we know that they'll be numbers without spaces – but it wouldn't hurt either.